# Same function gives different gas cost

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, out-of-gas

I'm trying to run a function repeatedly and it sometimes fails and sometimes passes, it's almost 50-50. I have already read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33998/different-gas-cost-for-same-operation) but it doesn't help in my case. Putting the code for reference.

```
struct TimeLock{
    uint256 _amount;
    uint256 _releaseTime;
}
uint releaseDuration= 120 * 1 seconds;  
uint resetDuration= 60 * 1 seconds ; 
uint timeStone;
uint penaltyGraceDuration= 120 seconds;
mapping(address => TimeLock[]) public lockData;
function lock(uint256 _amount) public {
    require(_amount>0 , "Less than minimum amount");
    
    TimeLock storage _timeLock;
    uint length= checkLength(msg.sender);
    checkEpoch(); 
    uint penalty; 
    uint totalClaimable;
    uint lockStartIndex;
    uint unlockStartIndex;
    
    (totalClaimable, lockStartIndex, unlockStartIndex, penalty)= userBalanceData(msg.sender);
    require(penalty==0, "Withdraw the amount on penalty");

    // Transfer to self and mint to depositer
    uint256 totalToken = token.balanceOf(address(this));
    uint256 totalShares = totalSupply();
    if (totalShares == 0 || totalToken == 0) {
        _mint(msg.sender, _amount);
    } else {
        uint256 what = _amount.mul(totalShares).div(totalToken );
        _mint(msg.sender, what);
    }
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    // update subtractedValue
    if(length> 0){
        TimeLock storage currentTimeLock= lockData[msg.sender][length-1];
        // After all are withdrawn the delete function deletes the releaseTime, 
        // Hence, subtraction overflow, [0,0,0];
        if(currentTimeLock._releaseTime != 0){
            uint epochTimeofLast= currentTimeLock._releaseTime.sub(releaseDuration).sub(resetDuration);
            if(block.timestamp.sub(epochTimeofLast) < resetDuration){
                currentTimeLock._amount=  currentTimeLock._amount.add(_amount);
            }else{
            // If the last deposit if before the current epoch (Create a new entry)
            _timeLock._amount= _amount;
            _timeLock._releaseTime= timeStone.add(releaseDuration.add(resetDuration));
            lockData[msg.sender].push(_timeLock);
        }
        }else{
            _timeLock._amount= _amount;
            _timeLock._releaseTime= timeStone.add(releaseDuration.add(resetDuration));
            lockData[msg.sender].push(_timeLock);
        }
    }else{ 
        _timeLock._amount= _amount;
        _timeLock._releaseTime= timeStone.add(releaseDuration.add(resetDuration));
        lockData[msg.sender].push(_timeLock);
    }

}
function userBalanceData(address _account) public view returns(uint, uint, uint, uint){
    uint length= checkLength(_account);
    if(length<=0) return (0,0,0,0);
    uint totalClaimable=0;
    uint i;
    uint unlockStartIndex;   // index where released funds start
    uint lockStartIndex; // index where lockedfunds start
    uint penaltyAmount;
    for(i= length; i>0 ; i--){
        if(lockData[_account][i-1]._amount>0 ){ //[20, 60, 40, 50] 
            if(block.timestamp > lockData[_account][i-1]._releaseTime){
                totalClaimable = totalClaimable.add(lockData[_account][i-1]._amount);
                unlockStartIndex=i-1;
            }else{
                lockStartIndex= i-1;
            }
        
            if(block.timestamp> lockData[_account][i-1]._releaseTime.add(
                    penaltyGraceDuration)
                ){
                    penaltyAmount= penaltyAmount.add(lockData[_account][i-1]._amount);
                }
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    //  If all the deposits are released
    if(block.timestamp > lockData[_account][length-1]._releaseTime){
        lockStartIndex= length;
    }

    return (totalClaimable, lockStartIndex, unlockStartIndex, penaltyAmount); 
}
```

Running the `lock()` function gives the gas cost error. Sometimes, it's says `out of gas` and sometimes it runs. What can be the issue?

Comment: Maybe there's a difference in the result of `checkLength()` for the different runs? As `userBalanceData` runs a loop based on `checkLength()`, that might make the tx go out of gas

Comment: @KenzoAgada No, that's not the case. It fails even when there is nothing in the array. So, after a lots of trials I also found out that it's failing when I'm doing multiple quick transactions. Like running the `lock` repeatedly. Also, the length of the array can have max value of 37, which isn't much. Any ideas after this new revelation?

Comment: Are you using hardhat ? A quick hacky trick is to use console.log in your contract (or use tenderly)

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth I'm doing the tests on Rinkeby testnet directly from Remix. I can see the gas consumption etc. here too. Can't seem to get any hints from the hashes. I'll attach a failed and a passed transaction hash, in the question for your reference.

Comment: If you verify your contract on Rinkeby, try using Tenderly (I'm not affiliated with them), it's quite powerful to debug transactions

Comment: You can also use (https://ethtx.info/) to decode your transactions

Comment: @cyberhawk The function is quite complicated it could be a bug, it could be the number of iterations, it could be the token contract. There are some odd things for example `TimeLock storage _timeLock;` is never initialized.